# Flutter AnimatedList - how to update an existing item?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animatedlist

AnimatedList has two methods, insert and delete for items in the list. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html

In my case I have complex items, and their properties can change.

How would I update an existing item in an AnimatedList if a property changes without removing or inerting the whole item again?

Would it be a simple setState call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setState method for updating the list item builder. [Reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

```
 setState(() {
                  items[index].checked = value!;
                });
```